# Bigquery Sql how many products were only sold in this year

Tags: sql, join, google-bigquery

I have a question regarding to Bigquery sql.
I am trying to find how many products were only sold in this year
e.g.

| Year | Product |
| --- | --- |
| 2022 | A |
| 2021 | B |
| 2021 | C |
| 2022 | B |

Therefore, there will be only one product that has been sold this year.

Is there a way to solve it without using `NOT IN` or`join`
Thank you!

Comment: Can you share the query you have tried?

Comment: I used not in and join which is really time consuming and I wanna optimise it.  SELECT count(distinct product)
FROM table 
WHERE year = '2022' and product not IN (select 
product
FROM table
where year != '2022')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `NOT EXISTS` with a correlated subquery as the following:

```
Select Product 
From table_name T
Where Year=2022 And
Not Exists (
  Select 1 From table_name D 
  Where D.Product = T.Product And
        D.Year <> T.Year
  )
```

Another option, you may use aggregation as the following:

```
Select Product 
From table_name
Group By Product
Having Count(*) = 1 And Max(Year) = 2022
```

Comment: I love the second solution! Thank you so much!